# How to display "Updating Workflow Status" progress bar in Excel status bar in VSTO?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I need a indicator in Excel VSTO to let user know the background task is running,  and I'd like to use Excel native progressbar like this:

[image]

Does anyone know how to show and hide this in VSTO?  Thank you.

Comment: I know Excel & VBA.... not C# & VSTO (it's on my list!).  Would this be along the lines of what you're looking for - `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp;
excelApp.StatusBar = String.Format("Processing line {0} on {1}.",rows,rowNum);`  Doesn't show a graphical progress bar, but allows you to update Excels status bar.

Comment: Hello @DarrenBartrup-Cook  I have tried excelApp.StatusBar ,  but it's only display a string in the left corner of status bar,  not show this animation progress bar.

Answer (score 2):

There is no trivial way to customize the status bar with a progress bar...

The [Application.StatusBar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.statusbar?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm133213);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue) property allows setting a custom text in the status bar, but not a progress bar. This property returns `false` if Microsoft Excel has control of the status bar. To restore the default status bar text, set the property to `false` - this works even if the status bar is hidden.

```
oldStatusBar = Application.DisplayStatusBar 
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True 
Application.StatusBar = "Please be patient..." 
Workbooks.Open filename:="LARGE.XLS" 
Application.StatusBar = False 
Application.DisplayStatusBar = oldStatusBar
```

If you want to display a progress bar with some text I'd suggest using task panes for that. Read more about that in the [How to: Add a custom task pane to an application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-add-a-custom-task-pane-to-an-application?view=vs-2019) article. On the user control you are free to use any .net controls.